# Automate pre-processing of sound (noise reduction, compressor, limiter)

Tags: audacity, compression, noise-reduction, automation, limiting

I use Audacity to pre-process sound before mixing the takes. I have found good settings for the relevant effects (noise reduction at 24 dB, compressor at 6:1, soft limiter at -10 dB) and the rest is mindless manual clicking through about 100 takes.

I like Audacity because of noise reduction learned from a profile; otherwise I can change to another tool. I tried scripting Audacity with pipes and it crashes (question: [Scripting crashes Audacity](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/scripting-crashes-audacity)).

How can I automate these pre-processing steps before mixing?

Comment: Now that Audacity has a new 3.0.0 release, you should try your script again with it to see if the issue has been corrected.  Always good to have options.

Comment: @DataProcessing Audacity 3 also crashes and I added an update in the original question: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/scripting-crashes-audacity

Answer (score 1):

For lack of answers, I programmed an AppleScript that controls the Audacity Graphical User Interface and achieves the same result. It loads a track with the noise and gets the noise profile, loads the track with the voice, removes the noise with that profile and the saved settings, and does the same with a limiter and a compressor.

```
set noise_track to "/path/to/noise/track.wav"
set voice_track to "/path/to/voice/track.wav"
set export_name to "voice-clean"

set short_delay to 1
set middle_delay to 5
set long_delay to 10

tell application "System Events"
    
    tell application "Audacity" to activate
    
    tell application "Audacity" to open noise_track
    
    delay short_delay
    keystroke "a" using command down
    
    
    tell process "Audacity"
        click menu item "Noise reduction..." of menu "Effect" of menu bar 1
    end tell
    delay short_delay
    
    repeat 2 times
        key code 48
        delay short_delay
    end repeat
    key code 49
    delay short_delay
    
    tell application "Audacity" to open voice_track
    delay short_delay
    
    --------------------
    -- Noise reduction
    --------------------
    
    keystroke "a" using command down
    delay short_delay
    
    tell process "Audacity"
        click menu item "Noise reduction..." of menu "Effect" of menu bar 1
    end tell
    delay short_delay
    
    key code 36
    
    delay long_delay
    
    --------------------
    -- Limiter
    --------------------
    
    tell process "Audacity"
        click menu item "Limiter..." of menu "Effect" of menu bar 1
    end tell
    delay short_delay
    
    key code 36
    delay long_delay
    
    --------------------
    -- Compressor
    --------------------
    
    tell process "Audacity"
        click menu item "Compressor..." of menu "Effect" of menu bar 1
    end tell
    delay short_delay
    
    key code 36
    delay long_delay
    
    keystroke "e" using {command down, shift down}
    delay middle_delay
    keystroke export_name
    delay short_delay
    key code 36
    
    delay long_delay
    
    --------------------
    -- Close two projects
    --------------------
    repeat 2 times
        keystroke "w" using command down
        delay short_delay
        key code 48
        delay short_delay
        key code 49
        delay 2 * short_delay
    end repeat
end tell
```